# How to calculate cumulative_sum within a terms aggregation nested inside a date_histogram [elastic search - 5.6]?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana

This is what I currently have :

```
"aggs": {
    "date_agg": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "document_date",
        "interval": "month"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "location_agg": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "loc_id",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "price_avg": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "price"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This gives me the document count and avg. price per location per month.
Only one problem though, it doesn't give me cumulative value of doc count and avg. price.

I wish to calculate count/rating per location per month which is cumulative.

I tried using cumulative_sum, but apparently you cannot apply that to a sub aggregation of a date_histogram.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share an example of the results you would like to get?

Comment: it should be array of months, where each bucket has array of locations, where each location has doc_count and avg_rating (but cumulative values from start date) - see example at https://api.myjson.com/bins/11vkwy

Comment: I don't see the cumulative values in your example

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve that by using [reverse_nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-aggregations-bucket-reverse-nested-aggregation.html).

Comment: I don't have a nested document. Not sure how i can use reverse_nested here. Can you modify my example above to show me how it might work?